# Let user change the source of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to let users choose their path for the source themselves. But I can't figure it out how I do this as I'm quite new in javascript.

```
<iframe id="test" src="testsrc"></iframe>
<button onclick="testfunction()">Click me</button>
```

This is what I got in my html file. I made a new folder just for testing stuff so it's easier.

```
function testfunction() {
    document.getElementById('test').src = "testsrc2";
};
```

Thats my js file, this works but it just changes the source to `testsrc2`, is there are solution so that user can choose their `exe` as an example from a program and then it will set the path from the `exe` as `src`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'exe'? From what I understand you need a way to get user's input, I believe HTML form elements to capture user entered input would be easy.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: With  **exe** i mean an application.